# Передача модели в метод класса (nest.js(наверно:)))

Tags: model, nest.js

Есть значит у нас обычная модель. И каким то образом мы вызываем у объекта RolesService метод create, хотя этот метод есть в самой модели, но где именно в этом коде, мы передавали методы модели классу RolesService?

[image: photo code]

[image: class]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

метод `.create` вызывается не у *объекта `RolesService`*, а у объекта `Role`, который хранится в свойстве `roleRepository`.

Для объявления свойства была использована [*краткая запись*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties), позволяющая объявить свойство добавив модификатор доступа к параметру в конструкторе.

Таким образом запись

```
class A {
    constructor(public b:B){}
}
```

равносильна

```
class A {
    public b: B;
    constructor(b:B){
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```